# How do I prove the axiom of replacement using a model with a Inaccessible cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm studiyng set theory in college and I found this theorem:

*If $V_\kappa$ is strongly inaccesible, then $V_\kappa \models ZFC$.*

The proof of other axioms I understood but there is this statement that I can't understand why.

*Since there is $g:a \rightarrow \kappa$ and $\bar{\bar{a}}<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ is regular we have $sup \{ g(c) :c \in a\}<\kappa$*

Can someone explain why $sup\{g(c):C\in a\}<\kappa$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only need the regularity of $\kappa$ here:

> If $\kappa$ is regular, $\vert a\vert<\kappa$, and $g: a\rightarrow \kappa$, then $\sup\{g(b): b\in a\}<\kappa$.

Fix a bijection $b$ between $a$ and an ordinal $\alpha$ of the same cardinality ($\alpha=\vert a\vert$ would be a natural choice). Then $g\circ b$ is a map from $\alpha$ to $\kappa$. Since $\alpha<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ is regular, there is no cofinal map from $\alpha$ to $\kappa$ (this is basically the definition of a regular cardinal).

So $g\circ b$ is not cofinal - that is, $\sup\{(g\circ b)(\beta): \beta\in\alpha\}<\kappa$. But since $\{(g\circ b)(\beta): \beta<\alpha\}=\{g(b): b\in a\}$ *(why? think about what you know about $g$)*, we've proved the statement we wanted to.